# can Geocat Bridge enable me to connect to existing PostGIS database and make edits through ArcGIS?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-server, boundless-suite, st-links

We are planning to set up a Webgis to share our GIS data on the web. Currently, we are on a desktop GIS and using ESRI's File geodatabase format. We are considering ArcGIS Server or using Opengeo suite. We want to retain using our ArcGIS Desktop but we plan to move our data to a Postgres/PostGIS database to enable multi-user viewing and editing when served on the web.

To be able to connect to a Postgres/PostGIS database without ArcSDE license, there are a number of solutions available, ST-links, GISquirrel, Geocat Bridge...

Geocat Bridge seems appealing cause we can directly publish mxd to Geoserver. But, it's not mentioned on their site whether we can **connect to existing  PostGIS data**. There is a mention that we **can load TO PostGIS** but not a thing mentioned on whether we can load data on ArcGIS Desktop **from  PostGIS.** Anyone who has tried Geocat Bridge? Is this possible in Geocat Bridge?

Comment: You cannot directly edit PostGIS in ArcGIS (without a third party tool/ extension) you have to have ArcSDE (workgroup or enterprise). QGIS you can. (We moved to qgis from esri)

Comment: @Mapperz, I know that. That's why I was asking about Geocat Bridge (that's a third party extension). I was asking if it's possible to edit PostGIS in ArcGIS desktop using Geocat Bridge.

Answer (score 2):

If you can load PostGIS data in ArcGIS, you can publish it to GeoServer using GeoCat Bridge. But GeoCat Bridge does not allow you to edit data stored in PostGIS within ArcGIS.